# How to remove "recommended items" from YouTube home page?

Tags: youtube

I want to see only my subscriptions on my YouTube home. Those recommendations are unnecessary pollution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a filter at the very top of the homepage:

[image: YouTube screenshot]

Switch to **Subscriptions** and you'll see only subscriptions...

Answer (score 3):

Or you can add [No Recommendation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-recommendation/ncjfodplfeiemdihehfgpgddelmhonil) Chrome extension.

> **No YouTube recommendations**
>
> By installing this extension, you can get rid of the recommendations of YouTube homepage, including videos and channels.

Answer (score 0):

Since YouTube likes to force us to look at crap we dont like, I use the Chrome AdBlock extension which allows me to hide certain areas of web pages as if it was an ad. Basically all I had to do was right click the recommended channels area and select AdBlock->Block this add, and a little window with a slider comes up and i slide it to the right until the whole recommended channels tab disappears. Now every time I visit my subscription page its gone for good! Not sure what the IE or Firefox equivalent is though.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In [**AdBlock Plus**](https://adblockplus.org/) (ABP) or a similar browser extension that can use ABP filters, simply add one of the ABP filter lists at the [**Customize YouTube with Adblock Plus**](http://youtube.adblockplus.me/en/) page. The ABP filter lists there can block the ff:

> #### YouTube Video Page
>
> Comments, Suggested Videos, Featured and Recommended Videos in the Endscreen, Sharing tab in the description,
> In-Video Annotations
>
> #### YouTube Homepage and Channel Page
>
> Related/Featured/Popular Channels on Channel Pages, Recommended Channels on the Homepage

Answer (score -2):

If YouTube doesn't provide this, its possible to make modifications to websites on a per-website basis using a Firefox browser plugin called [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/). If you use Firefox, go to [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/) and search for one that does YouTube modifications.

Ad-blocking plugins are also available for most browsers.

Answer (score -2):

Use Adblock in chrome and in customize options

pass the code

https://i.ytimg.com

for me it works superb as it shows everything as usual except the images so if u want u can still see the recommendations

Thanks 
Udhay [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the code"?